# Node.js - Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, request, content-type

```
setTimeout(function(){
request({
headers:{Authorization:'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-type':'application/json'},     
uri:'http//www.example.com',
method:'POST',
form:{'campaignid':('example'),
      'fields':["name","impressions"],
      'group':["tokenid"] }
}, function(err, res) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(res.body);
    json = JSON.parse(res.body);
});

}, 1000);
```

I'm receiving the error above. I tried using enctype:'application/json' and various the solutions and nothing seems to be working. I'm wondering what can I possibly do to ensure the response is returned in json format.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also could you edit your question heading as it says `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `json`. Thanks

Comment: Well that is the thing. I am requesting `json`. The error I'm receiving is as follow:     `{"timestamp":1462901209954,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported","path":"/extern/api/v1/report"}` **Sorry for the formatting, I'm new here.

Comment: The solution assumes that the HTTP request you are creating actually has

Content-Type:application/json instead of text/plain

Comment: I found the fix. I simply just changed 'form' to 'json' and got rid of 'content-type' in my header! Easy fix.